# .htaccess in wp-admin produces a redirect loop

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess

I've decided to take the advice of protecting the `/wp-admin` directory using .htaccess on a website which keeps getting hacked.

Whenever I upload .htaccess to `/wp-admin`, my browser says `/wp-admin` has a redirect loop.

This is `/wp-admin/.htaccess`:

> ```
> AuthUserFile /.../.htpasswd
> AuthType Basic
> AuthName “restricted”
> Order Deny,Allow
> Deny from all
> Require valid-user
> Satisfy any
> ```

A [server redirection checker](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/) says there is a **302 (Moved Temporarily)** redirect from `/wp-admin` to `/wp-admin`

If I delete `/wp-admin/.htaccess`, the redirect checker says there is still a 302 redirect from /wp-admin, but now it is to `/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

Bare in mind the server redirect checker is not logged into Wordpress.

Why does the presence of `/wp-admin/.htaccess` make `/wp-admin` redirect to itself?

Thanks.

PS - I am also using `Better WP Security`, but this made no changes to the site's `/.htaccess` in terms of `/wp-admin`.  i.e. I didn't cloak `/wp-admin`

Comment: I used your .htaccess file and created my own .htpasswd file.  It worked for me.  Not sure what is causing the problem.  There might be another Better WP Security rule that is interferring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redirection depends on server configuration. You need to add

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
```

to your main .htaccess to prevent redirection.
You can refer the article [Password-protect-wp-admin](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-password-protect-your-wordpress-admin-wp-admin-directory/) for more details

Comment: Nice one @Raja67.  I didn't expect this to work but it did.

Comment: It works. But, why?

Comment: @Jaec In the httpd config probably haven't got any error documents defined, so it is trying to return you to the base page, which throws an error, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but I recently ran into a similar problem and the `ErrorDocument` directive alone did not solve it for me. In my case, I had an incorrectly formatted .htpasswd file. When I recreated one using the [`htpasswd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html) tool, everything worked as expected.

Just thought I'd pass this along as an option in case someone else runs into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Next to "ErrorDocument 401 default" , you need to make sure the password file is readable by the webuser. In my case it was not and error log showed "[authn_file:error] [pid 15990] (13)Permission denied: [client 54.212.212.54:33556] AH01620: Could not open password file: /home/xxx/.htpasswd"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Raja67, I had to do 403 to get mine to work:

```
ErrorDocument 403 default
```