# login redirect problem - db charset issue?

Tags: redirect, login

I've got a WordPress site which is failing to do the login redirect. I think it has to do with the DB charset. The access log:

```
IP - - [09/Mar/2017:11:42:34 +0000]

"GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 4405 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"

IP - - [09/Mar/2017:11:42:35 +0000]

"GET /wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fanimalcare-clinic.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 21262 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

And I guess those %3A bits should be / so that's why its breaking. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is something issuing a 302 redirect from wp-login.php, I do not believe this is due to the DB charset, but some sort of login blocker.

The image below is the headers that are sent back to a request to wp-login.php.

[image: wp-login headers]

I am seeing a WWW-Authenticate header with a realm of "WCUK Password Protected Area" I could not find a plugin that uses those letters, can you edit your post to add the .htaccess file so we can see what is in there?

Comment: Hiya thanks for your reply, yeah I have implemtend server wide password protection of wp-login, with this in my httpd conf:

`<Files wp-login.php>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "WCUK Password Protected Area"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/htpass/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user`

but i have a hundred other WP sites on this server all the same and they work fine, its just this 1/100 that is breaking and I cant work out why, so tried to look at differences.

Comment: @anarki can you post the contents of that? or try deactivating that to see if it causing the redirect?

Comment: Hiya, yeah if I remove this htpass code it does fix the redirect on this site. But i need to keep it in place because this server is constantly hammered by brute force attempts.

Comment: @anarki Shot in the dark, but try this: `ErrorDocument 401 default` in your htaccess. ([Source](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130240/htaccess-in-wp-admin-produces-a-redirect-loop))